# When a service is stopped, should tear-down be necessary?

Tags: .net, service, object-lifetime

I'm writing my first .NET service with Visual Studio, and the IDE added a comment inside the `OnStop()` method:

```vb
Public Class AFirstService
    ' [...]
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
    End Sub
    ' [...]
End Class
```

Is this comment implying that this is somehow recommended to destroy objects when the service is stopped?

Comment: You can keep action which you want to execute on service stop. might you wan to log service stop time or anything

Comment: @Always_a_learner thanks, does a service stop terminate the process ?